# Short codes are not working in wordpress custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I am developing my own theme,Every thing is working fine,but short codes are not working.

I deactivated my theme and i checked with the twenty twelve theme,here the short codes are working.

i wrote the following code in index.php

```
echo do_shortcode('[layerslider id="1"]');
```

it is not working,even in pages too(`[layerslider id="1"]`)

but the following custom shortcode is working

i wrote this code in function.php

```
function codes()
{
echo "short code working";

}
add_shortcode('codes','codes');

echo do_shortcode('[codes]');
```

Comment: May be shortcode which you trying to implement in your custom theme is in twenty twelve theme.

Comment: Provide your code here.
How you add shortcode in theme ????

Comment: Sorry,no problem with short code.Problem with script files.No slider plugins are working.I tried with layer slider,wp slider..etc

Comment: Show your code if you want help

Comment: Updated the question with the code

Comment: @Manju How can we help with slider-related problems without the slider code?

Comment: @Daedalus: problem is not only with the slider,plugins and short codes are not working related to java script.

Comment: @Manju Make up your mind.  Above you say 'no problems with short code', and now you say the opposite; which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use return not echo in the function. I changed the shortcode name so it is different to the function name in this example.

Try this:

functions.php

```html
function codes() {
return 'Short code is working';
}

add_shortcode('codeworks','codes');
```

index.php

```html
echo do_shortcode('[codeworks]');
```

On the twenty twelve theme shortcodes you need to make sure you copy them into the new theme you are building.

Hope it helps.